# Are introductions in other languages suitable for internet videos?

Tags: youtube

I would like to start a YouTube Channel, playing games and reviewing them, possibly also some web development tutorials. One of my favourite shows is [Citizen Khan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Khan), and, as he is a muslim character, he greets people by saying "[As-salamu alaykum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-salamu_alaykum)", an arabic greeting often used by Muslims. While not islamic myself, I wish to introduce my videos by saying "As-salamu alaykum".

Within the Asian community, doing so would not be even though about, let alone considered innaproriate, however the internet is a multicultural platform, and I do not wish to offend anybody.

Would introducing myself in this way cause offense? Would it be considered inappropriate?

(Sorry if this doesn't fit with this rooms guidelines, it's my first question here)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I *don't* know if this is on-topic or not; I'll leave it for others to decide.

Simply, there are no rules. The question I would ask, is "would you do this in person?". That should give you your answer.

It intrigues me, however, that you wish to use a phrase from a culture and religion you are not a part of - so you really need to be extremely careful that you understand the implications of the phrase, as well as if it is used within society by non-Muslims. Cultural appropriation can be a serious insult to a culture; or it can be seen as appreciative and continuing their history.